# Deleting a large error log file

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems

We have a few PHP sites running on a windows server that are generating errors in the c:\windows\temp directory under a single log file.  This file is nearly 30gb at this point. When I try to list the directory contents with powershell, command prompt, or windows explorer the program locks.

Since I can't list the files I can't pinpoint the specific file to delete but we recently had this same issue on a staging server.

How can we locate and delete this file?

Comment: Locking up is not normal.  Do you have an unusually high number of files in that directory?

Comment: Hard to say since I can't get the directory contents to fully enumerate.  Because of this though I'm thinking that there probably is a large number.